# The property of being an index set is not computably invariant

Tags: computability

Let $\omega$ denote the set of natural numbers including $0$.

**Definition 1.** Let $A\subseteq \omega$. Then we call $A$ to be an index set if the following holds, $$\forall x\forall y((x\in A\land \varphi_x\equiv \varphi_y)\implies y\in A)$$where $\varphi_x,\varphi_y$ denotes the $x$-th and $y$-th [partial computable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_recursive_function) (with respect to some suitable numbering).

**Definition 2.** A computable bijection $f: \omega\to\omega$ is said to be a *computable permutation*.

**Definition 3.** A property $P$ of subsets of $\omega$ is said to be *computably invariant* if for any $A\subseteq \omega$ whenever $f$ is a computable permutation and $A$ satisfies the property $P$, $f(A)$ must also satisfy the property $P$.

**Problem.** Prove that the property of being an index set is not computably invariant.

I am not looking for a complete solution, but just some hint to get me started. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amongst the computable permutations are all **transpositions**: permutations which just swap some pair of elements. Often an easy way to show that some property isn't computably invariant *(or invariant with respect to some other collection of permutations)* is to show that it can be "killed" by a transposition. Note that transpositions are trivially computable.

So suppose $X$ is an index set; we want to try to show that there is some transposition $\pi$ such that $\pi[X]$ is *not* an index set. **This won't always be possible; along the way we'll think up some more restrictions on $X$**.

Clearly in order to be relevant a transposition has to swap something *in* $X$ with something *not* in $X$ (otherwise it just leaves $X$ as a whole unchanged). This indicates that we'll also want nontriviality, that is, we also want to assume $X\not=\emptyset$ and $X\not=\omega$. That's fine - there are indeed nontrivial index sets *(and it's unsurprising that we need nontriviality here)*.

So let $X$ be a nontrivial index set, pick $a\in X,b\not\in X$, and let $\pi$ be the transposition swapping $a$ and $b$ and leaving everything else unmoved. Is $\pi[X]$ still an index set?

*Hint $1$:*

> Use the padding lemma.

*Hint $2$:*

> By the padding lemma there is some $c\in\omega$ with $a\not=c$ but $\varphi_a\equiv\varphi_c$.

*Answer:*

> ... But then $a\not\in \pi[X]$ but $c\in\pi[X]$, so $\pi[X]$ isn't an index set.

*Postscript:*

> You might reasonably wonder whether appeal to the padding lemma was necessary - is there some "coarser" way to prove this, say using just the unsolvability of the halting problem? It turns out that the answer is **no**: something nontrivial about the standard enumeration of partial computable functions will be needed here, since if we work over a [Friedberg numbering](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/116708/89152) *every* set is an index set. For the same reason, an appeal to the padding lemma is necessary for the proof of Rice's theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the "Postscript". It was very interesting.